# Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium

Well, I'm trying to download an extension from the Chrome Store (I know how to add crx file using optiions). But I want to do it in other way!

When I tried to go to the extension page, I executed the click method, but it does not work (it said Unable to locate the element)

Here is the html:

```
<div role="button" class="dd-Va g-c-wb g-eg-ua-Uc-c-za g-c-Oc-td-jb-oa g-c" aria-label="Add to Chrome" style="user-select: none;" tabindex="0"><div class="g-c-Hf"><div class="g-c-x"><div class="g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label">Add to Chrome</div></div></div></div>
```

What I did in my code was:

```
wait(web,25).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"
))).click()
```

I can see in the top block of the html, the website has this element:

[image]

Comment: What is `/htm` at the beginning of that xpath?

Comment: Also, the `<body>` element does not appear to have 5 direct `<div>` child elements.  Where did you get that xpath value?

Comment: I got the xpath value of the element i need to click on, which i denoted on the image

Comment: HOW did you get it?  Because it appears to be wrong.  Did you type it yourself?

Comment: Just directly copied from the website

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/captcha-solver-auto-recog/ifibfemgeogfhoebkmokieepdoobkbpo?hl=en-US

Comment: So what is the `/htm` at the beginning supposed to be?

Comment: Oops, It was "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div".  sorry for mistyped it. But it still doesn't work for this XPath

Answer (score 0):

I mistyped my XPath, lol,
It is "/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"
not "/htm/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"